# How to update resource detail view without reloading the whole page in laravel nova?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I'd like to update an element value without reloading the whole page on the resource detail view page. I made a custom card for the device status enable/disable button. And I displayed the resource detail below my custom card. If I switch the device status button, the device status is changed to 0 or 1 in database. I did it with axios without reloading the page. But the problem is I can't update the Status field on the resource detail view without reloading the whole page. If I reload the page, then the status field shows the changed status correctly. Please look at this for understanding - https://prnt.sc/sd3jut

How can I update Status field without reloading the whole page? If possible, I'd like to do this in axios return section.

Thanks.